# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku, http-status-code-500

I'm running my PHP CodeIgniter app on Heroku and many users started getting 500 errors just today.

I checked the logs and found multiple entries for:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean
```

Doing some searching, it seems as though others have encountered problems with getTimestamp(). Are there any alternatives?

Here is the corresponding code:

```
public function compareDates($date){

    $LastFiveDates = $this->getLastFiveDates();

    $signUpDate = $this->getUserSignUpDate();
    $requested_date = $date;

    if($LastFiveDates[0] < $signUpDate){
        $signUpDate = $LastFiveDates[0];
    }

    if($signUpDate == NULL){
        $signUpDate = "09-25-2017";
    }

    $signUpDate_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $signUpDate);
    $signUpDate_ts = $signUpDate_dt->getTimestamp();

    $requested_date_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", $requested_date);
    $requested_date_ts = $requested_date_dt->getTimestamp();

    if ($signUpDate_ts > $requested_date_ts) {
        $this->noAccess();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Given that `DateTime::createFromFormat` is returning false, I'd look into why it's doing that - from the PHP docs for `DateTime::createFromFormat`: _Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure_

Comment: Also, you can not check if something is null by using `== null`. You need to use PHP's is_null() function, `if( is_null( $signUpDate ) )`.